# Recursive function in x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly

```
 int stirling(int n,int k)
  {

     if((n==0)&&(k==0))
           return 1;

     else if((n>=1)&&(k>0))
             return stirling(n-1,k-1)-(n-1)*stirling(n-1,k);

     else if(n>0)
            return 0;

    return 0;           
  }
```

I am trying to to write that function in a x86 Assembly and I could not figure out how to call the function `return stirling(n-1,k-1)-(n-1)*stirling(n-1,k);`

Anyone has an idea or can help me to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: How aod you make the initial call to this function?

Answer (score 2):

No different than any other function that calls this function.  Absolutely nothing special about recursion, just implement the C as you normally would.

n and k are basically local variables, you need local storage for the current instance of those variables.  The stack is a good place for this.  Or registers that are preserved on the stack when a call to any function is made.  (here again, nothing special, solution is not related to recursion, but standard implementation of C).

```
ldr r0,[sp-#N_OFFSET]
sub r0,#1
ldr r1,[sp-#K_OFFSET]
sub r1,#1
bl stirling
ldr r1,[sp-#N_OFFSET]
sub r1,#1
sub r4,r0,r1
ldr r0,[sp-#N_OFFSET]
sub r0,#1
ldr r1,[sp-#K_OFFSET]
push r4
bl stirling
pop r4
signed multiply r0=r4*r0
clean up stack for return
bx lr
```

No, that was not x86 assembler, I will let you translate to x86.  If this is homework please tag it as such or mention that it is not homework in the question.